# get people from custom list

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint

how can i get from my custom list, peoples , and give them permision on subsite that i create.

```
  public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

            base.ItemAdded(properties);
```

i know that i need get it from this property but i dont know how.
read about 20 blogs and cant find out from here.

```
            string subsitefirst = properties.ListItem["firstSub"].ToString();
            string subsitesecond = properties.ListItem["secondSub"].ToString();


           //take 1st and 2nd fields name and create with them subsites.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subsitefirst) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(subsitesecond))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sw-mss-01:23222/Worker1/"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //SPListItem listpeople = web.GetListItem
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPWeb newWeb = site.AllWebs.Add("worker1/" + subsitefirst, subsitefirst, "Site description", 1033, "STS#0", false, false);
                            SPWeb newSecondWeb = site.AllWebs.Add("worker1/" + subsitefirst + "/" + subsitesecond, subsitesecond, "Site description", 1033, "STS#0", false, false);

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }

                    }`
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've got some code. You should mention that this is regarding SharePoint. Would you like to tell us a little bit about this code you have here? It doesn't appear to have anything to do with your post except for the fact that it's written for SharePoint.

Comment: hm. This is event receiver. He invoke event added when somebody add line in my custom list. `string subsitefirst = properties.ListItem["firstSub"].ToString();`
1st and 2nd fields need to create subsites. 3rd field need to give user in this group permission.

Comment: Not related to your question but please change that `catch` to a `finally`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string domainUserName = properties.ListItem["user"].ToString();
string groupName = "site members"; // Use the group name you want to add the user to
SPUser user = newWeb.EnsureUser(domainUserName);
SPGroup group = newWeb.Groups[groupName];
group.AddUser(user);
// Rinse and repeat for the second web
```